# Android Studio using a horizontally scrolling recycler view to display 5 items at a time

Tags: android, listview, scroll, android-recyclerview

I have a horizontally scrolling recycler view that is displaying one row at a time very well. I want to know if it is possible to have the recycler view display five rows in a vertical list format, and then still have it scroll horizontally. Or should I just use paging?

Comment: Tried using GridLayoutManager instead of LinearLayoutManager??

Comment: You are a legend, I tried it with GridLayout just now and it works. Thanks!

Comment: Pleasure helping :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use GridLayoutManager for multiple Rows. LinearLayoutManager layouts all the items in a single row.